# Making sense of geometric series with index $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ : which sum can it be given?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found that $\sum_{t \in I} r^t $ is equal to zero :
$
\sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}} r^t 
= \sum_{t=-\infty}^{n-1} r^t + \sum_{t=n}^{\infty} r^t
$
I use the analytic continuation of geometric series
$\sum_{t=0}^\infty z^t= \frac{1}{1-z}$ (I don't sure)
$
\sum_{t=-\infty}^{n-1} r^t + \sum_{t=n}^{\infty} r^t
= \frac{r^{n-1}}{1-r^{-1}} + \frac{r^n}{1-r}
= r^n \frac{1}{r-1} + r^n \frac{1}{1-r} 
= 0
$
Does it make sense. I add some rational number with some series above it give a rational number in the form of p-adic numbers for some reason.

And does it have other answers if I use other ways of summation infinite serie?

Comment: And for what values of $r$ does your initial infinite sum converge?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Little initial remark : your indexing set $I$ should be $\mathbb{Z}$.

The problem with this doubly infinite geometric series is that it is divergent series whatever the value of $r$.

Let us take the case of $r=1/2$ :

- on the $+\infty$ side : $$1+\frac12+\frac14+\cdots$$ converges to $2$, but,
- on the $-\infty$ side, you get

$$r^{-1}+r^{-2}+\cdots = 1/r+1/r^2+1/r^3+... = 2 + 4 + 8 + ... $$

which is divergent (and not equal to $2 \frac{1}{1-2}$ !)

As one of the two sides always doesn't make sense (even if $r=1$), you cannot say that their sum is zero because you cannot even add them...

Answer (score 0):

It *is* an interesting question, something that even Euler pondered upon.

If $s(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} x^n$, then $x\cdot s(x) = s(x)$. If $x\ne 1$ then we "get" $s(x)= 0$. One can make some sense of the above. For instance, $1=0.999999\ldots$. But, in some sense, $\ldots 99999=-1$. So, indeed, $\ldots 9999.999999\ldots=0$.

Such a reasoning as above allows us to get the $p$-adic expansion of a rational number $r$, if we know the expansion of $-r$ in base $p$.

Another way to make sense of the above: we have

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}z^n = \delta_1$$

the delta function at $1\in S^{1}$, as a distribution on the unit circle, see the [Fourier inversion Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Relation_to_Fourier_series).